# How can I run __toString() using "yield". Do you have a solution?

Tags: php, class, generator, tostring, yield

I will use **__toString()** in a class in php. How can I run **__toString()** using "**yield**". Is there a solution?
My English is not good, I'm sorry. See example.

```
<?php

class test
{
    private $i;

    public function find()
    {
        $this->i = array(
            1,
            2,
            3
        );
        return $this;
    }

    public function data()
    {
        for ($this->i = 1; $this->i <= 3; $this->i++) {
            yield $this->i;
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if (is_object($this->i) && ($this->i instanceof \Traversable)) {
            return print_r(iterator_to_array($this->i), true);
        }
        return print_r($this->i, true);
    }
}
```

Run Example:

```
$a = (new test())->find();

echo $a;
```

Resut:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Run example:

```
$a = (new test())->data();

echo $a;
```

Result:
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Generator could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

Using `yield` in a function returns a [Generator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php), which doesn't implement `__toString`.

You can verify this by dumping the value:

```
$a = (new test())->data();
var_dump($a);
```

You can consume the generator with [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) and then print the result, like the way you've done in your class's `__toString` method:

```
$a = (new test())->data();
print_r(iterator_to_array($a));
```

---

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to output *Generator* generated values from `__toString`, then the following might be what you're looking for:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return print_r(iterator_to_array($this->data()), true);
}
```

And further:

```
$a = new test();
echo $a;
```

I'd like to emphasize that `data()` method returns a `Generator`, not an instance of your `test` class. Thus you can't just echo a result from `data()`.

Comment: I know that. That's not the answer I'm looking for. How to do it with "__toString ()". Please read the question.